# fportfolio returns zero portfolio weights for GMV optimization and Error in if (STATUS != 0) { : argument is of length zero for tangency portfolio

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

I'm trying to do portfolio optimization for work. Currently learning how to do it in fportfolio package. I'm following the book: Portfolio Optimization with R/Rmetrics.

Here is the code given for Global minimum variance optimization:

```
lppData <- 100 * LPP2005.RET[, 1:6]
globminSpec <- portfolioSpec()
globminPortfolio <- minvariancePortfolio(data = lppData,spec = globminSpec,constraints = "LongOnly")
print(globminPortfolio)
```

The book's output is as follows:

```
Title:
MV Minimum Variance Portfolio
Estimator:  covEstimator
Solver:     solveRquadprog
Optimize:   minRisk
Constraints: LongOnly
Portfolio Weights:
SBI SPI SII LMI MPI ALT
0.3554 0.0000 0.0891 0.4894 0.0025 0.0636
Covariance Risk Budgets:
SBI SPI SII LMI MPI ALT
0.3553 0.0000 0.0891 0.4893 0.0025 0.0637
Target Return and Risks:
mean mu Cov Sigma CVaR VaR
0.0105 0.0105 0.0986 0.0986 0.2020 0.1558
Description:
Mon May 4 13:44:58 2009 by user: Rmetrics
```

However, my output is:

```
Title:
 MV Minimum Variance Portfolio 
 Estimator:         covEstimator 
 Solver:            solveRquadprog 
 Optimize:          minRisk 
 Constraints:       LongOnly 


  Portfolio Weights:
SBI SPI SII LMI MPI ALT 
  0   0   0   0   0   0 

Covariance Risk Budgets:
SBI SPI SII LMI MPI ALT 


Target Returns and Risks:
mean  Cov CVaR  VaR 
   0    0    0    0 

Description:
 Wed Jul 19 14:06:22 2017 by user: tmpj81
```

For the tangency portfolio, the book's code is:

```
 tgSpec <- portfolioSpec()
    setRiskFreeRate(tgSpec) <- 0
    tgPortfolio <- tangencyPortfolio(  data = lppData,  spec = tgSpec,  
    constraints = "LongOnly")
    print(tgPortfolio)
```

It produces this error:

```
Error in if (STATUS != 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

I am following the instruction book exactly and I produced these errors with both the data provided in the package and my own data.

Does anyone know how I can deal with this? I also noticed that in the book's output for GMV, there is mean,mu,cov,sigma,cvar,var whereas in mine there is only mean,cov,cvar,var.

Comment: Your code worked with no issue on my end. Try to restart?

Comment: I did. 3 times. Could I be missing something in R?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you tried adding these lines: `> minriskSpec <- portfolioSpec()
> targetReturn <- getTargetReturn(ewPortfolio@portfolio)["mean"]
> setTargetReturn(minriskSpec) <- targetReturn`

Comment: hey, yes I've tried the min risk portfolio as well. gives zero weights too. the equal weights portfolio from the start of the chapter works though.

Comment: Hello all who've read this. I've run this code on another computer and it works. I don't know whats wrong with my R.

Comment: The worst kind of bug is the ones you don't know when they happen. I have the same issue on my laptop, while I didn't have such problems on my work PC. I don't know if it is the version of R or the fPortfolio version.